# Bibliography is not updated in Beamer after deleting citiation when compiling with LuaLaTeX and Biber

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, luatex, citing, biber

In Beamer, when deleting, respectively commenting out a citation, the bibliography doesn't remove the now deleted/unavailable citation reference inside the Bibliography of the presentation.

Rerunning the compilation, as sugested in [this solved Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650237/bibliography-is-not-updated-after-deleting-citiation-when-compiling-with-lualate/650239#650239), could not fix the issue.

E.g.: Version after commenting out the first citation

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%Here comes a citation \cite{merriam2022}.

Here comes a citation \cite{wikipedia2022}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography file named `sources.bib` has following content:

```
@online{merriam2022,
  title={Merriam-Webster},
  publisher={Merriam-Webster},
  year={2022},
  urldate={2022-07-06},
  url={https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fun},
}

@online{wikipedia2022,
  title={Wikipedia},
  year={2022},
  urldate={2022-07-06},
  url={https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software},
}
```

Comment: How do you compile? With `lualatex->biber->lualatex`? For me this works fine for the example you show.

Comment: Can you show your `.log` and `.blg` files?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: it worked! thank you. Please add the `lualatex->biber->lualatex` compilation method into an answer, so I can vote and select it as valid answer. All the best.

Comment: I linked to a duplicate instead. The premiss of that question is a bit different, but ultimately the same answer applies.